# Bind Pipeline id to Experiment in Azureml Python SDK V1

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azuremlsdk, azure-ml-pipelines

I am submitting Experiment as
python```
experiment.submit(self.pipeline, name=job_name, tags=tags, **kwargs)

```
where: `self.pipeline` is `azureml.pipeline.core.Pipeline object.`. But after submition, in azure portal it has no published pipeline id. Instead it there is `-` symbol.

I tried find out if it has any `id` parameter, but resultless.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the provided information it seems, your pipeline is not published.

[image]

To publish your pipeline, you can check this [documentation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/machine-learning/v1/how-to-deploy-pipelines.md)

Once you publish the pipeline, you will be able to get the details.

[image][image]